# Индекс вне границ массива

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**При нажатии кнопки должно подсчитать количество элементов массива начинающихся с А.**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ch = 0;
    String X = TextBox1.Text;
    char A = 'A';
    string[] split = X.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ' ', '.', ':' });
    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        if (s.Trim() != " ")
        {
            if (s[0] == A)
            {
                ch++;
            }
        }
        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(ch);
    }
}
```

Отсылает к строке Строка 24:                 if (s[0] == A)

Comment: Всё верно, Split мтжет выдавать пустые строки, если не указать опцию RemoveEmptyEntries, а s.Trim никогда не будет равен " ", так как метод как раз удаляет пробельные символы, т.е. данный if можно вообще убрать.

Comment: Как правильно, в итоге он должен выглядеть? 

Видимо я совсем многое не знаю, если не могу понять вас сейчас)

Comment: убрав  if (s.Trim() != " ")
        {

Я все равно получаю ту же ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private static readonly _charSeparators = new char[] { ' ', ' ', '.', ':' };
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        var text = TextBox1.Text;
        var firstChar = 'A';
        var count = text.Split(_charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              Count(x => x[0] == firstChar);
        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
    }
```

Comment: Благодарен, это немного сложнее чем мне пытаются "разжевать" в университете, но дает возможность узнать где были пробелы в знаниях)